# Buddypress - Grab data of HTML5 email field

Tags: wordpress, html, buddypress

Need some input on this one!

I am using the buddypress function:

`bp_get_profile_field_data('field=Email:');`

to grab the user email (test@email.com) from their profile. 
As the email field is HTML5, the function is grabbing the following HTML from the field:

```
ahref=mailtotest@email.comrelnofollowtestemail.coma
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this and if there is a way to grab just the content of the field and not the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with BuddyPress (nor its inner workings), however, I have a couple of options you can use to parse the e-mail address from the bp function output.

Option 1: **String Function**

```
var vText = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=Email:');
var emailAddress = vText.substring(12,vText.length-25);
```

This option is best if the email address is always sandwiched between "ahref=mailto" and "relnofollowtestemail.coma". Based on the pattern of the latter half of that sandwich, I'm guessing that half will change based on email address. So then there is another option.

Option 2: **Regular Expression**

```
var vText = bp_get_profile_field_data('field=Email:');   
var re = /mailto(.*)rel/;
var emailAddress = re.exec(vText)[1];
```

Hopefully, one of these two options helps.

```js
var vObj = document.getElementById("results");
var vText = vObj.innerHTML.trim();

// Option1: String Function
//vObj.innerHTML = vText.substring(12,vText.length-25);

// Option2: Regex
var re = /mailto(.*)rel/;
vObj.innerHTML = re.exec(vText)[1];
```

```html
<div id="results">
  ahref=mailtotest@email.comrelnofollowtestemail.coma
</div>
```